# Error NU5012: Unable to find 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built

Tags: nuget, visual-studio

I am trying to create a nuget package of my .NET Framework project - '`MyProj.csproj`'. For this, I have created nuspec file using nuget.exe commands and have changed the assembly info as well.

Now, on running the below command -

```
nuget pack MyProj.csproj
```

I am getting below error -

```
Attempting to build package from 'MyProj.csproj'.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin'.
Packing files from 'C:\Projects\SolutionName\src\Feature\MyProj\code\bin'.
Using 'MyProj.nuspec' for metadata.
Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
Error NU5012: Unable to find 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

I can see `EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0.nupkg` file inside packages folder on path `C:\Projects\SolutionName\packages\` but I am not sure how to resolve this error.

Please suggest a resolution.

Comment: what is your nuget version?

Comment: @PrashantTomar  - "nuget.exe - recommended latest v5.6.0". I have downloaded nuget.exe.

Comment: Tried these links?
1. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7131 
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886069/10329199
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380753/10329199

Comment: Thanks @PaulsonMaclean, solution suggested in one of these links worked for me.

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Comment: sorry this is not an answer but not able to comment so asking here, which link helped to solve this problem? please let me know which link you flowed?

Comment: Try to add a parameter for your pack command "-PackagesDirectory pathTopackagesfolder".
Probably it's solution directory